# Always display a button

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-relativelayout

I created a scrollable table layout in xamarin . I want a button to be always displayed in the bottom of screen (the help button),no matter if I scroll the table,the button is shown.

I put the button on a relative layout. How can I do the relative layout (which is on the linear layout) , not to be scrollable and also always to be on screen?

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/linearImag">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <TableLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mytb">
        <TableRow
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/myav"
                android:layout_width="97.0dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_height="32.0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2.0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp" />
            <Button
                android:text="Help"
                android:id="@+id/bhelp"
                android:layout_column="3" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="187.5dp"
            android:layout_height="48.0dp">
            <TextView
                android:text="Code"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:id="@+id/myt"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_width="105.7dp"
                android:layout_height="34.0dp" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Products"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:id="@+id/myt"
                android:layout_width="73.0dp"
                android:layout_height="36.0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Cantity"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:id="@+id/myt"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="80.0dp"
                android:layout_height="23.0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp" />


        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="103.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <Button
                android:text="Save"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:id="@+id/btnsave"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have post the code with some little changes in your code. As ScrollView have just one child limitation, I used RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearImag" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/mytb"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:minWidth="25px" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="187.5dp"
                    android:layout_height="48.0dp"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:minWidth="25px" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/myt"
                        android:layout_width="105.7dp"
                        android:layout_height="34.0dp"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:text="Code"
                        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/myt"
                        android:layout_width="73.0dp"
                        android:layout_height="36.0dp"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
                        android:maxLength="20"
                        android:text="Products"
                        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/myt"
                        android:layout_width="80.0dp"
                        android:layout_height="23.0dp"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
                        android:text="Cantity"
                        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="103.5dp"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:minWidth="25px" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:minHeight="25px"
                    android:minWidth="25px"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnsave"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:text="Save" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bhelp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearImag"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:text="Help" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,very helpful answer! I managed to do it using scrollview just for table layout.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code provided below,
in ScrollView you can use any component like textview , tablelayout etc...
Button always displayed in the bottom of screen (the help button),no matter if you scroll the table,the button is shown.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"/>
   </ScrollView>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Help"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is a useful design for a particular screen size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I posted my code. Is not any other option to make my relative layout not to be scrollable?

Comment: hi Andru,
         You can use it for any device and any screen size.

Hi Mady, I have just added the modified code. Have a look.

Answer (score 2):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           //inner content here
        </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="your_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I posted my code. Is not any other option to make my relative layout not to be scrollable?